# How to converting following Swift code in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to learn self-sizing UICollectionView Cell techniques using a [certain tutorial](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios8-day-by-day-day-37-autosizing-collection-view-cells). I can't figure out how to write this following swift code in objective-c:

```
if let cvl = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    cvl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 75)
  }
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Could you post some more code? How do you get `collectionViewLayout`? Also, just out of curiosity, why are you trying to convert from the newer language to the older language? Do you need backwards-compatibility?

Comment: I do not know swift so while following the tutorial, I am doing it in objective-c. There is not much code actually mentioned in the tutorial that I have mentioned and linked in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, the `if`-`let` construction is equivalent to `nil`-checking in Obj-C. The `as` keyword is used for casting. The question mark makes it an optional type, which is a value that can hold `nil` or a value. Non-optional values cannot hold `nil`, and if you attempt to "unwrap" a `nil` optional you will get a runtime error.

In Obj-C (this *should* be equivalent):

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout * cvl = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout)collectionViewLayout;
if (cvl){
    cvl.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(150, 75);
}
```

[CGGeometry documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html)